# Fourier series sketching

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, graphing-functions

[image]

Whenever I am asked to draw fourier series, is it correct to first draw the function on the interval first (in this case 0<= x < pi), then extend the the graph to the desired interval ([-2pi,2pi]in this case). If the function given is odd function, we extend it by reflecting the thing we sketched corresponds to the boarder line (in this case the lines are x=0, x=pi, x=-pi); if it is an even function, we copy the sketching to those region without reflecting.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you supposed to sketch the sum of the whole Fourier series (not just some partial sum)? Then that would be the same as the graph of the function, extended to be even and periodic. Yes, your approach is correct.

Comment: I am asked to sketch the f(x) but not the sum of the f(x)

Comment: It seems to me that in part(b) f(theta)=theta is an odd function but the solution drew it as if it is an even function. Can you please explain why would it be the case? (Please see the attached picture below)

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series converges to a certain extension of the given function.

1. cosine series on $[0,L]$: even periodic extension
2. sine series on $[0,L]$: odd periodic extension
3. full Fourier series (sines and cosines on $[-L,L]$): periodic extension.

To obtain the required extension,

1. Define $f(x)=f(-x)$ on $[-L,0)$ and proceed to 3.
2. Define $f(x)=-f(-x)$ on $[-L,0)$ and proceed to 3.
3. Extend periodically by $f(x+2L)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ambiguity on the function definition. It is defined as $x-\pi$ on $(0,\pi]$ and even with period $2\pi$, so that it is $-x-\pi$ on $(-\pi,0]$.

Anyway, the Fourier series is to be computed on the range $(-2\pi,2\pi]$, there will be no $2\pi$ harmonic.